# important files are not in list , all some files go in untract files list?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I am using a Git Repository to manage my project,
Now when i try to commit i see there are some impoertant file like content/image , scripts , etc files in untrack files 
Why?

Is there any way to resolve this?

Regards,
vinit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "git add [wildcard or directory or file(s)]" first to add your files to the versioning system GIT. Manual page is here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html

And the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book) is worth a read.

Also I liked [gitready](http://gitready.com/) very much.

Happy coding

Comment: So basically if you just wanted to add all your files in your directory to git, use " git add . ". But be aware that you might also be adding files from your project whcih you would not want to add (project files from eclipse or intellij for example). So be sure to first take a look at the ".gitignore" file and list your unwanted directories or files there first.

Comment: i have allready add a gitignor file and there is still add a dll and pdb files

Comment: You should really go through one or two git tutotials if you want to start with git on a good beginning. To understand what you are doing here is elementary

Answer (score 1):

If your Git repo has been initialized on GitHub (and then cloned), it is likely to come with a `.gitignore` (as well as a `README.md`, and even a `LICENSE` file).

Check if those files aren't ignored by the rules in the `.gitignore`.

You can do that with:

```
git check-ignore -v scripts
```

You can edit that file to remove the rules you don't want, then a git add . will add:

- the modified `.gitignore` files
- the files that were previously ignored.